# How to write a generic function to convert any enum value to its string representation?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My goal is this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    TheA,
    TheB,
    TheC
}

const strValue = enumToString(MyEnum, MyEnum.TheA)
```

strValue should be "TheA".

My closest attempt looks like this:

```
function enumToString<T extends { [name: number]: number|string }>(myenum: T, myenumvalue: number){
    return myenum[myenumvalue] as string;
}
```

The problem is, that this is still not type safe. One could use some totally different enum and the compiler would still accept that. For example:

```
 const strValue = enumToString(TotallyDifferentEnum, MyEnum.TheA)
```

Basically I need a generic constraint which ties both function parameters together. Something like this:

```
function enumToString<T extends { [name: number]: number|string }, K extends typeof T>(myenum: T, myenumvalue: K)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a constraint to the 2nd parameter : `T[keyof T]` instead of `number`.

Also note that the key of your `enum` is of type `string`.

```
function enumToString<T extends { [name: string]: number | string }>(myenum: T, myenumvalue: T[keyof T]) {
  return myenum[myenumvalue];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAKgC2AQQBoNs8AhYzXYAYTQF801RJsB7AFwEMAbHuACIBLAGYjgAJ1AckrFFABibNlEZoRYEAGMOQtiCgsIWNgGUOEoSADmAHiyGAHh1AATAM5R5AbRBcIwABcUO4WVtYAusHIAEaSUAA+IWE2qgB8ABQQcEbBWIRQ2UYAbrxgQdjeANbAcGwi2BEAlF4kUhxgEgZFyN49kKU85REA3AxMWvqhyRIAamXAUAC8hsgm5pY2GfCyEAU7yAB01PgtAPRnUADyANJokyDToXMLAEzLq5DrKdYZJtx8QSicRSEAyZD7RBHE7nS4AOVu9ymHBm8yGwAAzB8jN9Nr9-rx+MIxJJpLsCgTAcSQWSjko2LDrncgA)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily get the raw value of any enum string using
For Kotlin

```
YourEnum.YourEnumValue.rawValue
```

In your case

```
const strValue = MyEnum.TheA.rawValue
```

Update:
For TypeScript

```
MyEnum[MyEnum.TheA]
//this returns string 'TheA'
```